# Is there an easy way to detect changes within an InfoPath 2007 Form Services section?

Tags: infopath, infopath-forms-services

I'm looking for tips/tricks for dealing with changes on fields within an InfoPath section.  Basically, I'd like to be able to set a dirty flag for a section.  I'm using InfoPath 2007 with Forms Services.

Currently, my approach would be to add rules to every field within the section to update the dirty flag but that is too painful and messy.  Is there some simple solution that I am missing?

As a corollary, if anyone has tip/tricks for toggling a field between read only and not read only, that would be greatly appreciated as well.  My only solution there is to duplicate the fields in another section and hide/show the appropriate section based on logic.  I realize that I could do this with views as well but both are ugly solutions.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to add a bunch of InfoPath rules; that it seems that writing some form code is probably your best bet.

The xmlchangedeventhandler below looks to be of some use.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.infopath.xmlchangedeventhandler.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  I should have mentioned that I'm trying to avoid code, though.  This is using SharePoint Forms Services and I want to avoid having to publish it through Central Administration (which is required for forms with code).

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be a mishmash of rules/hidden fields if you can't use code (even then it aint gonna be pretty!)

Comment: I guess so.  Hopefully the next version of InfoPath helps with this.